# Setting location for Debug and Release output file in CMake(Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am using other library's source code and it uses CMake in creating project.
Thus I am using CMake in generating Visual Studio Project.
I would like to change the location of release and debug output file from default which are in the project folder itself.

How can I change that? What command do I have to append to CMake file?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the location of binary file output with the `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH` variable. It's default is the value of `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`.

```
EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH 
    set this variable to specify a common place where CMake should put all executable files (instead of CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)
    SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
```

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of CMake / MSVC use:

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY $<0:>)
```

For building libraries, rather than executables, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78197002/3220983