# In CMake, how do I work around the Debug and Release directories Visual Studio 2010 tries to add?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I'm trying to build one of my CMake-based projects from a couple of years ago with Visual Studio 2010 and I'm running into problems to do with the output directory for a project. Visual Studio has always been very keen on adding Debug/ and Release/ subdirectories when outputting binaries, and for various reasons I've always been very keen on removing them - now that I'm using a new version of CMake and a new version of Visual Studio, the old workaround in CMake no longer seems to work, and I'm looking to find out the "new" way of doing it.

With a previous version of CMake (2.6) and a previous version of Visual Studio (2008), I used the following:

```
IF(MSVC_IDE)
    # A hack to get around the "Debug" and "Release" directories Visual Studio tries to add
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${targetname} PROPERTIES PREFIX "../")
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${targetname} PROPERTIES IMPORT_PREFIX "../")
ENDIF(MSVC_IDE)
```

This worked fine, but no longer seems to do the trick. Please does anyone know of a similar but more up-to-date workaround that will work with CMake 2.8.6 and Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you want precisely, but I would recommend to take a look at the available [target properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#section_PropertiesonTargets), similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561754/cmake-changing-name-of-visual-studio-and-xcode-exectuables-depending-on-configu/6563692#6563692).

It depends a bit on what you want exactly. For each target, you could manually set the [library_output_directory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aLIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) or [runtime_output_directory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aRUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) properties.

```
if ( MSVC )
    set_target_properties( ${targetname} PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${youroutputdirectory} )
    set_target_properties( ${targetname} PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${youroutputdirectory} )
    set_target_properties( ${targetname} PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${youroutputdirectory} )
    # etc for the other available configuration types (MinSizeRel, RelWithDebInfo)
endif ( MSVC )
```

You could also do this globally for all sub-projects, using something like this:

```
# First for the generic no-config case (e.g. with mingw)
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${youroutputdirectory} )
set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${youroutputdirectory} )
set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${youroutputdirectory} )
# Second, for multi-config builds (e.g. msvc)
foreach( OUTPUTCONFIG ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES} )
    string( TOUPPER ${OUTPUTCONFIG} OUTPUTCONFIG )
    set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${youroutputdirectory} )
    set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${youroutputdirectory} )
    set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${youroutputdirectory} )
endforeach( OUTPUTCONFIG CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES )
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - it turns out I was looking for the ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_{config} properties on the target. Cheers! :)

Comment: I do exactly the same and it works until e.g. add_executable(test test.cpp)
get_target_property(test_EXE test LOCATION) is called, it still has the D:/Codebase/test/bin/$(Configuration)/test.exe any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Which variable will hold the output folder for the current project (Without working with the different configurations)? Namely if I work on release will point to the `x64\Release\` and if I run debug mode will point to the `x64\Debug\` folder? Namely I don't want to change it, I just want to access it.

Answer (score 13):

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html explains that:

> Multi-configuration generators (VS, Xcode) append a per-configuration
>   subdirectory to the specified directory unless a generator expression
>   is used.

Thus, the only workaround is to use a generator expression. One cool way to do it is by using $<0:> at the end of your path. So if your path is /what/ever/, you will need to replace it with /what/ever/$<0:>.

Example with the target: Nuua and the path: C:/Nuua/bin/

```
set_target_properties(nuua PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY C:/Nuua/bin/$<0:>)
```

Comment: What does `$<0:>` signify? Just a generator expression which evaluates to nil?

Comment: It evalutes to an empty string.  Without the expression the generator is free to set `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` to per-configuration sub-directory.  Having the expression forces the generator to evaluate and set this property to the expected directory!

Answer (score 7):

In current versions of CMake you can use a generator expression for [`LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) to avoid the configuration-specific suffix.

I just added `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:>`, which always expands to nothing, to mine. This looks a bit weird, but it does work, and it's not so weird you can't explain it with a brief comment:

```
# Use a generator expression so that the specified folder is used directly, without any
# configuration-dependent suffix.
#
# See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html
set_target_properties(library PROPERTIES
                      LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY my/folder/$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:>)
```

Comment: I wish there was a SO feature for third party to review questions on CMake over time and mark answers made 6 years later as "forget everything mentioned before, THIS is how you do the X in 2019"

Comment: I've a bit confused with word "Debug" in the suggested expression, possible it can be simplified to "$<$<CONFIG:>:>" ?

Comment: @PavelK. I think the `$<CONFIG:>` test requires a configuration name. Perhaps you could use `$<0:>` or something instead, though.

Comment: Erik's answer quotes CMake documentation that explains why this works.

Answer (score 3):

Big thanks to Erik's for the hint to use $<0:>

If you have multiple targets that you want that solution for you could do something like

```
# Get Targets in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
get_property(current_targets DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS)
foreach(TARGET ${current_targets})
    set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES
                        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/$<0:> 
                        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/$<0:>
                        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/$<0:>)
endforeach()
```

to perform it for all targets in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} without having to add it for each executable/library individually

Answer (score 0):

Combining this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74080336/3220983,
with those prior to me here, I solved how to do this for STATIC libraries (.lib) using **CMake 3.27** and **Visual Studio 2019**:

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY $<0:>)
```

Note how there is:

- no config spec involved
- the `$<0:>` generator resolves to nothing, i.e. the root output path with no sub directory
- a static library is an "archive" not a "library"
- I did this within each sub project I needed it, unlike Tim's nice global solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/70712709/3220983, but where he gathers of them all (from one place in the code dynamically) into top level directories, I left them in their respective sub directories where the build process "normally" does (i.e. mirroring other compilers / platform contexts e.g. GCC on Linux etc)